# Angular 16: The new `CanActivateFn` guard does not inject singleton services

Tags: angular

The injected services from the guard (CanActivateFn) are not singleton. Even though all of the services are declared singleton:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

And I have make sure that the only providers is the `app.component`:

```
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, RouterOutlet, NotificationComponent],
  providers: [
    HttpModule,
    NotificationService,
    MetaService,
    AuthService,
    CookieService,
    NavigationService,
  ],
  template: `
    <ng-container *ngIf="initialized()">
      <app-notification></app-notification>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </ng-container>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
```

I have put the static counter / flag to track how many times the service is constructed:

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class AuthService {
  auth = signal<IAuth | undefined>(undefined);

  public static instanceCounter = 0;

  constructor(
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private nav: NavigationService,
    private notification: NotificationService
  ) {
    AuthService.instanceCounter++;
    this.initAuth();
  }

  .....
```

The counter increases up to 2 when the guard is triggered, it creates another one:

```
export const AllContentGuard: CanActivateFn = (route, state) => {
  const auth = inject(AuthService);
  console.log("AUTH: " + AuthService.instanceCounter);
  return !environment.protectAllContentWithAuthentication ? true :
    inject(AuthService).isUserInRoles(['registered']) ? true : inject(NavigationService).router.createUrlTree(['login']);
};
```

On my first page load (example go to Http://localhost:4201/) which guarded by the `AllContentGuard` above, it creates a new instance of the `AuthService` even before the singleton service `AuthService` is created from the app initialization.

How can I prevent this and just use a singleton service? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By having your `AuthService` in your providers list & as `providedIn:root` you will spawn 2 differents instances depending of which injector is used :

- The root injector for the guard
- The component injector for the `AppComponent` and all its children.

Just remove `AuthService` from the `providers` list and you should be fine.